# Why don't my jqueryui sortable table work?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I don't understand why I'm unable to sort table rows. I have sortable working fine with lists, but something is wrong with my table.
Here is my table:

```
<table class="table table-sm" id="tilbehor_table"> 
  <tbody>
  <tr>
     <th>Navn</th>
     <th>Pris</th>
     <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tilline_1">
     <td>Nina nattbord Hvitmalt</td>
     <td>1195</td>
     <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm tilsorthandle" title="Endre rekkefølge"><span data-feather="menu"></span></button>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tilline_2">
     <td>Odel gavl&nbsp;rutet 150 cm Skumring blå</td>
     <td>3995</td>
     <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm tilsorthandle"  title="Endre rekkefølge"><span data-feather="menu"></span></button>
     </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is my JS:

```
$('#tilbehor_table tbody').sortable({ axis: "y", handle: ".tilsorthandle" });
```

When I run the js, I can see that sortable classes are added to the table, but I'm unable to to use the handler to click and drag rows.

Comment: Does my answer work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cancel option in sortable which is by default set to `"input,textarea,button,select,option"`. According to documentation, `cancel` option do the following.

```
 Prevents sorting if you start on elements matching the selector.
```

So here sorting is prevented if using these default selectors to sort. Set the value of cancel option to an empty string and it works.

```
   $('#tilbehor_table tbody').sortable({ axis: "y", handle: ".tilsorthandle", cancel: ''});
```